# A problem regarding neighborhood of a point in Normed linear space

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space (real or complex). Let $x,y\in X$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$. Suppose that $\|\alpha x+\beta y\|=1$ for **real numbers** $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove that if $B_{\delta}$ is an open ball (of radius $\delta$) about $\alpha x+\beta y$, then there exists an $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $\widetilde{\beta}$ is real and $\widetilde{\beta}<\beta.$
2. $\|\widetilde{\alpha} x + \widetilde{\beta} y\|=1$.
3. $(\widetilde{\alpha} x + \widetilde{\beta} y)\in B_\delta.$

By pictures in case of two-dimensional space, the assertion seems true. However, I cannot prove it explicitly. Any hint or answer will be appreciated!

Comment: In fact, since only the span of two vectors in involved, it suffices to prove this in two-dimensional normed space.

Comment: One thing is here that the space may be complex and we want our scalars to be real@GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

**Hint: Sketch of Proof**

Define $z=\alpha x+\beta y$. Since $z$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$, then all the three vectors $x,y,z$ are coplanar and since they are all unit vectors, then they lie on the same unit circle. Hence $B_\delta$ intersects that unit circle exactly at its own center (i.e. center of $B_\delta$) and a non-zero part of the unit circle, falls inside $B_\delta$. Now find a point $\tilde \alpha x+\tilde \beta y$ on the intersection of the unit circle and $B_\delta$ such that $\tilde\beta<\beta$.

Comment: Thankyou@mostafaayaz.

Comment: how to ensure that $\widetilde{\beta}<\beta$?

Comment: Can we see that $\tilde{\beta} > \beta$ on one side of $z$ and $\tilde{\beta} < \beta$ on the other side?

Comment: I believe it is very true, but cannot prove explicitly@GEdgar